# Run callback function with different values

Tags: go, callback, asynccallback

I ran the createCB from 2 different places and with different value
one time with the value "state"
and 2nd with the value "restarts"

```
a := createCB("state",wd)
b := createCB("restarts",wd)

func (c *CollectorWatchDog) createCB(field string, wd *cpwdObj) func() (interface{},[]attribute.KeyValue) {
    var value interface{}
    return func() (interface{},[]attribute.KeyValue) {
        err := c.runWDCommand("cpwd_admin","list")
        if err != nil {
            return nil, nil
        }
        
        if strings.Compare("state",field) == 0 {
            value = wd.state
            fmt.Println("createCB")
            fmt.Println("field")
            fmt.Println(field)
        } else if strings.Compare("restarts",field) == 0 {
            fmt.Println("createCB")
            fmt.Println("restarts")
            fmt.Println(field)
            value = wd.restarts
        } 
        
        labels := wd.getStateRestartLabels()
        return value,labels
    }
}
```

I sent the CBs to a different function and activated them, one by one, but just the first one has activatead.

what can be the reason for that?